# Execute SOOT API correctly for 3 address code

Tags: java, api, soot

I'm having trouble running the SOOT API. I'm using

`java -cp soot-2.5.0.jar soot.Main -f jimple test`

I run into the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load classfile: java.io.ObjectInputStream at 

at soot.coffi.Util.resolveFromClassFile(Util.java:75)
    at soot.CoffiClassSource.resolve(CoffiClassSource.java:39)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchy(SootResolver.java:215)
    at soot.SootResolver.processResolveWorklist(SootResolver.java:155)
    at soot.SootResolver.resolveClass(SootResolver.java:124)
    at soot.Scene.tryLoadClass(Scene.java:417)
    at soot.Scene.loadBasicClasses(Scene.java:990)
    at soot.Scene.loadNecessaryClasses(Scene.java:1061)
    at soot.Main.run(Main.java:167)
    at soot.Main.main(Main.java:141)
```

How to reverse this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the standard library on your classpath. Try -pp